# How to add a header row to a list of child views of an expandablelistview that uses simplecursortreeadapter

Tags: android, header, expandablelistview, simplecursortreeadapter

I'm using a simplecursortreeadapter to populate an expandablelistview and want to have a row at the top of all the children views that has titles for the data.

1. Group 1 Name *[Expanded]*

   - **Header (Date, Name, $)**
   - Child 1 (07/12/2017, Chad, 50.00)
   - Child 2 (08/11/2017, Mike, 63.21)
2. Group 2 Name *[Expanded]*

   - **Header (Date, Name, $)**
   - Child 1 (03/25/2017, Ken, 23.97)
   - Child 2 (01/25/2017, Will, 101.11)
3. Group 3 *[Collapsed]*

Is it possible to have the textviews that contain the 3 sets of header text (Date, Name, $) to only appear when the group is expanded? Since the SimpleCursorTreeAdapter handles adding the cursor data into the views, I'm not sure how to add a row to that or how to achieve this. Is this possible?

Edit: Here is my adapter class:

```
package com.example.myproject.michaelc.billme;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.database.MergeCursor;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter;

import com.example.myproject.michaelc.billme.data.BillMeContract;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class PayeeCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {

private final String LOG_TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
private PayeeActivity mActivity;
protected final HashMap<Integer, Integer> mGroupMap;

// No cursor is added to the adapter so that it only runs when the CursorLoader runs, instead of every time the activity does
public PayeeCursorAdapter(
        Context context,        // The activity where the adapter will be running
        int groupLayout,        // The .xml layout file for the group layout
        int childLayout,        // The .xml layout file for the child layout
        String[] groupFrom,     // String of column names in the cursor that is the data for each group item
        int[] groupTo,          // The ID of the views in the group layout that display the column from the groupFrom String[]
        String[] childrenFrom,  // String of column names in the cursor that is the data for each child item
        int[] childrenTo) {     // The ID of the views in the child layout that display the column from the childFrom String[]

    super(context, null, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childrenFrom, childrenTo);
    mActivity = (PayeeActivity) context;
    mGroupMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
}
@Override
protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {

    int groupPos = groupCursor.getPosition();
    int groupId = groupCursor.getInt(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(BillMeContract.PayeeEntry._ID));

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getChildrenCursor() for groupPos " + groupPos);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getChildrenCursor() for groupId " + groupId);

    mGroupMap.put(groupId, groupPos);
    Loader<Cursor> loader = mActivity.getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(groupId);

    if(loader != null && !loader.isReset()) {
        mActivity.getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(groupId, null, mActivity);
    } else {
        mActivity.getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(groupId, null, mActivity);
    }
    return null;
}

public HashMap<Integer, Integer> getGroupMap(){
    return mGroupMap;
}
}
```

Comment: can you post your adapter class?

Comment: @KiranBennyJoseph Here you go

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can possible .

you can also see this link , hope you will get your solution.

http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/tips/Android-expandable-listview-header.htm

```
package android.widget.expandablelistview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.ExpandableListScenario;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

public class ExpandableListWithHeaders extends ExpandableListScenario {
private static final int[] sNumChildren = {1, 4, 3, 2, 6};
private static final int sNumOfHeadersAndFooters = 12;

@Override
protected void init(ExpandableParams params) {
    params.setStackFromBottom(false)
            .setStartingSelectionPosition(-1)
            .setNumChildren(sNumChildren)
            .setItemScreenSizeFactor(0.14)
            .setConnectAdapter(false);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    final ExpandableListView expandableListView = getExpandableListView();
    expandableListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < sNumOfHeadersAndFooters; i++) {
        Button header = new Button(this);
        header.setText("Header View " + i);
        expandableListView.addHeaderView(header);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sNumOfHeadersAndFooters; i++) {
        Button footer = new Button(this);
        footer.setText("Footer View " + i);
        expandableListView.addFooterView(footer);
    }

    // Set adapter here AFTER we set header and footer views
    setAdapter(expandableListView);
}

/**
 * @return The number of headers (and the same number of footers)
 */
public int getNumOfHeadersAndFooters() {
    return sNumOfHeadersAndFooters;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll check it out and see if I can get it to work.